# If you catch a Pokémon does your chances of meeting it in the wild increase?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I caught a Pickachu, and retrieved it form the box at the Pokémon Centre. I returned to Santalune Forest and the next several Pokémon were more often Pikachu. 10 Pikachu to 10 non Pikachu. I thought they were supposed to be rare; they certainly were before I caught one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not normally, however, when you have a Pokemon with the ability [Static](http://www.serebii.net/abilitydex/static.shtml) in the lead, your chances of encountering electric type Pokemon increases to 150%.

If Pikachu's encounter rate is for example is 10%, it becomes 15%.

If your Pikachu isn't in the lead when you saw the other Pikachu, then you were just lucky :)

Comment: It was in the lead.